# Binding: 'JSONObject' does not implement interface member 'IMap.ContainsKey(Object)'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting the following error when trying to do **Android Binding.**

```
'JSONObject' does not implement interface member 'IMap.ContainsKey(Object)'
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can check this doc [Metadata.xml Transform File](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#Metadata.xml_Transform_File), by the way, which lib are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48841988/6155481

N.B. Make your partial class extend `global::Java.Lang.Object` and `global::Java.Lang.IComparable`