# does not implement interface member 'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)'

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I have an .aar file of android. I am trying to use it in my xamarin.android app. I followed the steps from the given in the link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/

but when I am trying to build my library I am getting following error

"does not implement interface member 'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)'"

I found some solution for it where it is mentioned that in metadata.xml we need to add some attribute. so I added the following line there

```
path="/api/package[@name='com.logicjunction.ljindoorandroidsdk']/class[@name='FloorPlanBeaconsMapping']/implements[@name='java.lang.Comparable']"
```

name="type">java.lang.Comparable>

But still getting same error. How I can fix this?

Comment: Have You tried to add a partial class to Additions folder with method `int Java.Lang.IComparable.CompareTo(Java.Lang.Object obj)` ?

Comment: do you have any sample code for it?

Comment: check this: https://sorokoletov.com/2016/02/29/material-date-time-picker-available-for-xamarin-android-apps-bindings/ starting from: "To solve 3rd problem we need to add a partial class to Additions folder:"

Comment: I tried the given solution but still getting same issue. Is might any issue in the line added in metadata.xml file?

Comment: Could you please share the .arr file?

Answer (score 11):

So I had the same problem which I could solve it by helping the compiler in adding those lines in `Metada.xml` (`Transforms` folder) :

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='<JAVA_PACKAGE_NAME>']/class[@name='<CLASS_NAME>']">
    <method name="compareTo" return="int" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public">
        <parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Object" />
    </method>
</add-node>
```

Comment: This was the cleanest way to fix it for me. Thanks for this!

Comment: in this example, what should be the package name and class name?

Comment: @theNoob It would be whatever the package and class names are of the method you're adding using this node. So if the class containing the method is com.my.package.AwesomeClass, the package name would be com.my.package, and the class name would be AwesomeClass.

Answer (score 10):

Getting the error when build the library without interface implementation IComparable.CompareTo:

[image: The error']

To resolve the issue, need create at "**Additions**" folder a partial class of the library class that requires interface member implementation 'IComparable.CompareTo(Object)', like below:

[image: partial class with interface IComparable]

**The namespace should be the same like at binding library**, in this case, it is: "*Hirondelle.Date4j*".

```
using Java.Lang;
namespace Hirondelle.Date4j
{
    public partial class DateTime : Object, IComparable
    {
        int IComparable.CompareTo(Object obj)
        {
            return CompareTo((DateTime)obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the library should be built with success.

Comment: I the line `return CompareTo((DateTime)obj)` I get the error `The name 'CompareTo' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: There is should to check installed packages and references. 
CompareTo located at namespace Java.Lang->IComparable->CompareTo into Mono.Android.dll. Also install Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 packages for the library.

Comment: Same issue with me not getting CompareTo